# How can I use spring boot actuator? Official steps didn't work

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, jar, spring-boot-actuator

I tried to use spring boot actuator to observe my simple application, expecting to observe an application in my office.

My original endpoint worked, but actuator's endpoints did not work with following commands.

Executed commands:

- `gradle build`
- `java -jar build/libs/HelloWorld.jar`
- `curl http://localhost:8080/greet/hello` -> "Hello world!" was
  printed (EXPECTED)
- `curl http://localhost:8080/health` -> status 404, error: not
  found (UNEXPECTED)

It seems that actuator's packages were not included, though I compiled spring-boot-starter-actuator-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar.

Could you tell me what was wrong?

My environment:

- Developing server in my office
- Cent OS 7
- Javac 1.8.0_101
- Spring boot 1.5.6
- Gradle 4.6

Structure of my app:

```
HelloWorld - build.gradle
           - setting.gradle
           - lib
           - src/main/java - Application.java
                           - GreetController.java
```

Here are my codes:

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://192.168.131.247:8081/nexus/content/repositories/maven2/" }
    }

    dependencies {
            classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.6.RELEASE")
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath fileTree('./lib') {
            include '**/*.jar'
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'


sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
targetCompatibility = '1.8'

// configure project
configurations {
    provided
    //compile.exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
}
sourceSets {
    main.compileClasspath += configurations.provided
    test.compileClasspath += configurations.provided
    test.runtimeClasspath += configurations.provided
}

repositories {
    maven { url "http://192.168.131.247:8081/nexus/content/repositories/maven2/" }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: './lib', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile fileTree(dir: './lib', include: ['*.jar'])
}

springBoot {
    executable = true
}
```

settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'HelloWorld'
```

lib directory

```
classmate-1.3.3.jar
commons-collections4-4.1.jar
commons-compiler-2.7.8.jar
commons-daemon-1.0.15.jar
commons-dbcp2-2.1.1.jar
commons-io-2.5.jar
commons-lang3-3.5.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar
commons-validator-1.6.jar
diffutils-1.2.1.jar
ehcache-2.10.4.jar
hibernate-validator-5.3.5.Final.jar
httpclient-4.5.3.jar
httpcore-4.4.6.jar
jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar
jackson-core-2.8.9.jar
jackson-databind-2.8.9.jar
jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.8.6.jar
jackson-dataformat-smile-2.8.6.jar
jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.8.6.jar
james-2.3.2.1.jar
janino-2.7.8.jar
jboss-logging-3.3.1.Final.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar
jcommander-1.48.jar
jna-4.4.0.jar
joda-time-2.9.5.jar
jopt-simple-5.0.2.jar
json-20140107.jar
json-smart-2.2.1.jar
junit-4.12.jar
lang-mustache-client-5.5.2.jar
libs.txt
log4j-api-2.7.jar
logback-classic-1.1.11.jar
logback-core-1.1.11.jar
lombok-1.16.18.jar
opencsv-4.1.jar
securesm-1.1.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
snakeyaml-1.15.jar
spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-gradle-plugin-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar
**spring-boot-starter-actuator-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar**
spring-boot-starter-aop-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-jetty-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-test-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-web-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar
spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-data-keyvalue-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar
spring-oxm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar
spring-test-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar
testng-6.10.jar
tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar
tomcat-embed-el-8.5.16-sources.jar
tomcat-embed-el-8.5.16.jar
validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
```

Application.java

```
package com.example.app;

import java.util.Arrays;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

GreetController.java

```
package com.example.app;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/greet")
public class GreetController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String greet (){
        return "Hello world!\n";
    }
}
```

I followed Susan' comment, but it didn't work too.

What I did:

- create src/profile/application.yml
- update build.gradle

application.yml

```
endpoints:
  enabled: true
  sensitive: false
  health:
    enabled: true
    sensitive: false
  info:
    enabled: true
    sensitive: false
  loggers:
    enabled: true
    sensitive: false
```

In build.gradle, I added following lines

```
......
sourceSets {
    main.resources {
        srcDirs "src/profile"
    }
    ......
}
......
```

Comment: Thank you Susan, but your suggestion didn't work. The same error occured.

Comment: Why do yu have a lib folder with dependencies instead of letting the dependencies figure that out? Basically beats the purpose of having those. Your dependencies are weird to as they include jetty and tomcat (it should be either one not both). You are also mixing versions of modules (Jackson and Spring) which is troublesome as well. Looks like you try to outsmart both gradle dependency management and spring boot for the configuration. Finally those `starter` dependencies don't contain anything but a `pom.xml`/`build.gradle` for dependency management.

Answer (score 1):

In your application.properties file add the following

```
endpoints:
  enabled: true
  sensitive: false
  health:
    enabled: true
    sensitive: false
  info:
    enabled: true
    sensitive: false
  loggers:
    enabled: true
    sensitive: false
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be curl **http://localhost:8080/actuator/health**  unless you change actuator endpoint using

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      base-path: <endpoint>
```

Also in yml file it should be like

```
endpoint
  health:
    enabled: true
```

its not `endpoints`

I follow a different way to expose endpoints though as the following, this also should work

```
management:
  endpoints:
      exposure:
        include: health,info
```

So your application.yml should be like

```
endpoint:
  health:
    enabled: true
  info:
    enabled: true
  loggers:
    enabled: true
```

or

```
management:
  endpoints:
      exposure:
        include: health,info.loggers
```